# How to calculate case function based on AVGs

Tags: sql, case, average

Hi just started learning sql on Khan Academy. I'm working on the Challenge: Gradebook, link to my spinoff below.

From their base table I added in a class column (math and english) and assigned each student a row so they each have a math grade and a english grade. What I would like to do is calculate each students AVG grade and then assign an letter grade based off the averages using the case function. The issue I am running into is that the letter grades are being assigned based off of one row of the number grade, rather than the average grade. Wincifer for example is given a grade of an F, despite having an avg_grade of a 78, which I want to return a C.

https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/spin-off-of-challenge-gradebook/5755493070979072

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: Please include a simplified version of your data, your current query, what it returns and what you would like to be returned in the question itself.

Comment: Something different than what’s in the Khan Academy spin-off link?

Comment: I suggest you read these two posts from the Help section: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)

Comment: Not to say that you won't get help here, but it's much more likely if you show all of the information in your question and explain what you have tried so far